# How to pronunce the suffix "-less"

Tags: pronunciation, suffixes

I know how to pronounce *less*. But in words with the suffix *-less*, it sometimes sounds like /lis/, other times like /les/. Which is true?

Comment: This is the kind of pronunciation that varies widely between dialects and between sociolects, so I would urge caution if you are trying to find a "true" or "correct" answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to depend on the word. The OED gives the pronunciation of *less* as /lɛs/ (rhyming with *stress*). However, it gives the final syllable of *regardless* as /ləs/ (rhyming with the final syllable of *virus*) and the final syllable of *timeless* as either /lis/ (rhyming with *kiss*), or /ləs/.

Comment: I really wouldn't read too much into this -- I think all you're observing is that the OED phonetics compiler working on the "R" section had a slightly different opinion to the compiler working on the "T" section. I seriously doubt there's any such consistent difference that depends on the individual word in question.

Comment: (At a detailed phonetic level, the final vowel of "timeless" may incidentally be slightly more "ɪ"-coloured under influence of the ɪ portion of the initial diphthong -- but the broad transcriptions in question certainly aren't intending to show this level of analysis -- I think it's just an anomaly.)

Comment: @ Neil Coffey: I can't accurately reproduce here the symbol which the OED actually uses in the case of ‘timeless', but it is one which ‘represents free variation between /ɪ/ and /ə/’.

Comment: That makes sense, only I think I would extend it to all instances of the suffix -less (in the absence of contrary evidence).

Comment: It may persist as regional dialect, or it may simply be a broader trend. The observation that either is possibly acceptable seems to stand true for now. I generally only enunciate suffixes carefully when in formal settings or when I'm trying to clarify something. It depends on how fast I'm talking and how excited I am, as well.

Comment: @BarrieEngland, you looked up the wrong word in the OED! You need the suffix -less - the OED gives /lɪs/.

Comment: The OED's differing pronunciations for *timeless* and *regardless* might be explained if  there is secondary stress on *-less* in *timeless* but not *regardless*. I pronounce the stress that way, even if the OED doesn't (although I have /ɪ/ for both).

Comment: @PeterShor, Upton, Kretzschmar, and Konopka (2003), authors of the Oxford Dictionary of Pronunciation, give the following explanation, "If the preceding syllable contains a high front vowel or a diphthong ending in a high front vowel," then ɪ is the norm, otherwise there is a free choice between ɪ and ə (p. xviii). They use ᵻ as a reduced (unstressed) variant of ɪ.

Comment: @Alex B. That is quite true, but the fact remains that the OED’s pronunciations for ‘regardless’ and ‘timeless’ are as I gave them.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're observing is a change in progress. If you were to survey (UK) speakers a few decades ago, you'd probably find that most had /lɪs/. If you survey speakers today, you'll probably find most have /ləs/. (Except in the actual word "less", of course.)

A trend in English seems to be that, at least in the southern UK pronunciations, the language is moving towards having schwas instead of /ɪ/ in unstressed syllables generally.

Comment: One more way in which New Zealand leads the world.

Answer (score 0):

The LPD-3 (Wells 2008) says the following:

**-less** ləs, lɪs. *In singing, a strong-vowelled form* les *is usual*.

*Preference poll, BrE (for the word* careless, *disregarding votes for* -les *and from respondents who do not distinguish* ɪ *from* ə *in this position*): -ləs 74%,-lɪs 26%."

Alan Cruttenden (2008) reports that /ləs/ is preferred by the younger generation in the UK.

cf. EPD-11 (Jones 1956) gives /lis/ only (e.g. for "careless") vs. EPD-15 /ləs/ as primary and /lɪs/ as secondary (Roach, Hartman, and Setter 2006).

Answer (score -1):

It is better to pronounce it as /les/ , rhyming with mess.

Comment: Mmmmm only if you mean "better" as in "not the way that most native speakers pronounce it". Not sure that's necessarily "better"...

Answer (score -2):

The variation with this is very colloquial, so /les/ is more correct.

On a few minutes thought, so dont take it as gospel, it seems that the pronunciation is /les/ if preceded by a consonant e.g. regardless is more often /les/.

And the pronunciation is /lis/ if preceded by a vowel e.g. timeless is more often /lis/

Comment: But "m" and "d" are ***both*** consonants. The "e" in "time" is not pronounced.

Comment: Yes `m` is a consonant but the `e` **is** there, as such the less on timeless is preceded by a vowel, pronounced or otherwise. As I said, it has very colloquial variation (as we can see by the accepted answer) and even has contextual variation. Maybe I should have said "*immediately* preceded by a vowel".